# CSS styles are not being applied inside iframes in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, iframe

I have included my css in index.html and tried to use the styles inside the iframe but its not being applied.

```
<iframe name="glcframe" id="glcframe" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="1200" ng-src="home/test.html" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iframes basically emulate a browser inside a frame - none of your styles from your framing page will be applied within the iframe

Comment: I will also add that there is no way to do this except place the styles you want inside of the framed page: home/test.html

Comment: I do not think AngularJS will help with this... what you are doing seems strange to me since you apparently framing an HTML file that is within your project. Framing a page is a dangerous/questionable practice - and should be avoided.